# Bounded Arithmetic and Counting

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, computational-complexity, bounded-arithmetic

Let $\mathcal{L}=\{0,S,+,\cdot,=,<,X,R,S\}$ be the language of arithmetic with three additional predicate symbols $X(v)$, $R(v,u)$ and $S(v,u)$.

Let $\phi(x),\psi(x,y)$ and $\eta(x,y)$ be formulas in $\mathcal{L}$. Define the formula $\Theta_e(\phi,\psi,\eta)$ in $\mathcal{L}$ for some $e\in \mathbb{N}$ which says:

1. $\phi(0)$
2. $\psi$ is a partition of $\{x:\phi(x)\}$ into classes of size $e$.
3. $\eta$ is a partition of $\{x:\phi(x)\land \neg x=0\}$ into classes of size $e$.

> **Theorem**. For every fix prime number $p,q\in \mathbb{N}$, ${\bf I}\Delta_0(R,S,X)+\Theta_p(R,S,X)+\{\neg \Theta_q(R',S',X'):R',S',X'\in \Delta_0(R,S,X)\}\not \vdash \bot$

Proof. One of the proofs of this theorem can be found [here](http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~krajicek/ens.ps).

> Q1. Is there any similar result for counting modulo a composite number? For example is ${\bf I}\Delta_0(R,S,X)+\Theta_7(R,S,X)+\{\neg \Theta_6(R',S',X'):R',S',X'\in \Delta_0(R,S,X)\}$ consistent?
>
> Q2. Suppose that the theory above is consistent. Does it imply separation of complexity classes like $AC_0[6]$ and $NP$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1: Yes. The paper you linked to in the question actually proves the theorem for every pair of natural numbers $p,q$ such that $p$ has a prime factor that does not divide $q$ (in other words, $p$ does not divide any power of $q$).

Q2: No. Even at the best of times, you'd only get the conclusion that the classes are different *in some model of the theory*, not necessarily the standard model. However, the theory here is too weak even for that. Passing to the second-order language as used e.g. by Cook and Nguyen, you'd need to prove separation from the theory $V^0(6)$ to make things work. Your schema consists of instances of the $\forall\Sigma^B_0$ mod-6 counting axiom, which is weaker than the $\forall\Sigma^B_1$ axiom of $V^0(6)$ asserting the *existence* of suitable mod-6 counting functions.

Comment: Why current method like Ajtai forcing does not settle question 1?

Comment: Sorry, I realized I confused several of these problems related to modular counting. Q1 is in fact settled. But since it is settled in the very paper that you linked to in the question, I wonder whether you meant something else?

Comment: Ah! you are right!. I thought that paper proves the case for $p$ and $q$ are both prime.
By the way, by separation from $V^0(6)$, you mean proving consistency $V^0(6)+\Theta_7(R,S,X)$ or separating it from another theory?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you want. If $V^0(6)\ne V^1$, then $V^0(6)$ has a model in which $\mathrm{AC^0[6]\ne NP}$. If $V^0(6)\nsupseteq V^0(7)$ (which is a stronger assumption), it even has a model where $\mathrm{AC^0[6]\nsupseteq AC^0[7]}$. Since $V^0(7)\vdash\neg\Theta_7$, the consistency of $V^0(6)+\Theta_7$ is a yet stronger assumption.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know why something like Ajtai forcing or similar arguments do not work for proving $V^0(6) \not = V^1$?